# A series transformation

Tags: sequences-and-series

Why the equality

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \sum_{i=\lfloor{\frac{k}{n+1}}\rfloor(k-n)}^{k-\lfloor{\frac{k+1}{n+1}}\rfloor(k-n)} \binom{n}{i} \binom{n}{k-i} $$ $$ = \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \sum_{i=0}^{k} \binom{n}{i} \binom{n}{k-i} $$

holds?

I couldn't find any explanation.

Edit: $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the greatest integer smaller than or equal to x. And

$$ \binom{n}{i} $$

is the familiar combination function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \sum_{i=0}^{k} \binom{n}{i} \binom{n}{k-i}\\
=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \sum_{i=0}^{k} \binom{n}{i} \binom{n}{k-i}
+\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \sum_{i=0}^{k} \binom{n}{i} \binom{n}{k-i}\\
=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \sum_{i=0}^{k} \binom{n}{i} \binom{n}{k-i}
+\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \sum_{i=\color{red}{k-n}}^{\color{red}n} \binom{n}{i} \binom{n}{k-i}\\
=\sum_{k=0}^{2n} \sum_{i=\lfloor{\frac{k}{n+1}}\rfloor(k-n)}^{k-\lfloor{\frac{k+1}{n+1}}\rfloor(k-n)} \binom{n}{i} \binom{n}{k-i}. 
$$ 
The index change marked by red color can be done due to the fact that for $k\ge n+1$
$$
\binom{n}{i} \binom{n}{k-i}=0
$$
for $i<k-n$ and $i>n$.

Thus the floor function does nothing else as preventing summation over zero terms.

Comment: Great solution, thank you. That was really what I was looking for.